# Issue N1QL query with CouchbaseNetClient 3.0.5

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I have installed the CouchbaseNetClient 3.0.5 nuget package. I see that the namespace Couchbase.N1QL is missing in the nuget and thus I'm not able to use the select query on bucket. Could someone please help me out on how to implemenet N1QL query using CouchbaseNetClient 3.0.5 nuget package

Comment: cluster.QueryAsync<dynamic>   https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/current/howtos/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.